# transform data.frame in R

Tags: r, transform

My data.frame looks like this:

```
ID  val     val_2
16  500     300
16  5       2
16  14      7
```

Is there any function in R to transform my  data frame  to look like this:

```
ID  16  val 500 5   14  val_2   300 2   7
```

?

Comment: `lapply(df, unique)` will work for this example while still providing a useful. structure. If you really want the bizarre output you mention, you could wrap this in `unlist`, but all the elements will become character.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this formula is suitable.

```
tmp <- data.frame(ID = c(16,16,16),val = c(500,5,14),val_2 = c(300,2,7))
```

ID val val_2

1 16 500   300

2 16   5     2

3 16  14     7

```
library(reshape)
unique(melt(tmp))
```

result:

variable value

1       ID    16

4      val   500

5      val     5

6      val    14

7    val_2   300

8    val_2     2

9    val_2     7

column of data.frame is fixed